# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 - Readonly checkbox is covered by lock icon

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 (8.1.1.1005). When setting a Yes/No field on a form to read only and having it displayed as a checkbox, the "lock" icon covers the checkbox so the user can not see the value.

[Example image of lock icon covering checkbox field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUq5g.png)

The lock icon doesn't cover the checkbox when the Yes/No is displayed as a list or two radio buttons, and the checkbox displays as intended when not read only.

Is there a setting somewhere that can fix this or is it just a bug in this version of CRM? We recently upgraded to this version of CRM and that is when the issue started.